# How to restore state after a restart from chosen source (not necessarily last checkpoint)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I've been trying to restart my Apache Flink from a previous checkpoint without much luck. I've uploaded the code to GitHub, here's the main class:
 https://github.com/edu05/wordcount/blob/restart/src/main/java/edu/streaming/AppWithKafka.java

It's a simple word count program, only I'd like the program to continue with the counts it had already calculated after a restart.

I've read the docs and tried a few things but there must be something stupid missing, could someone please help?

Also: The end goal is to produce the output of the wordcount program into a compacted kafka topic, how would I go about loading the state of the app by first consuming the compacted topic, which in this case serves as both the output and the checkpointing mechanism of the program?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Flink's checkpoints are for automatic restarts after failures. If you want to do a manual restart, then either use a [savepoint](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/ops/state/savepoints.html), or an [externalized checkpoint](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/ops/state/checkpoints.html#retained-checkpoints).

If you've already tried this and are still having trouble, please provide more details about what you tried.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the interest. I've updated the branch with my attempt at starting my app with a pre-loaded state where the word "mario" has a count of 3 before any new messages are processed (I implemented the _CheckpointedFunction_ interface) but it throws an exception. The original use case is more complex but getting this simpler scenario to work should suffice. We possibly also have different notions of restart. To me, a restart constitutes any number of nodes (possibly all) going down, happen on occasion and should not require manual intervention other than restarting the machines.

Comment: Btw, even the previously submitted code does not restart from where it left off, so the word counts are restarted every time I start the app :(

Comment: Could we retake this question please?